Oracle Apex OOB Failed Login Timeout
I'm using Oracle Apex version 22.2.
My application has a custom authentication scheme that requires users to login in through MFA. Step one is entering their username/password, step two is they must validate their login via sms or email.
I want to be able to use a specific part of the code in the apex_authentication.login function. Whenever this function returns false, you get an incremental timeout before you can attempt to log in again: 
These settings are set in the Apex Administration --> Manage Instance --> Security --> General Settings.
My issue is I can not simply call this function on the initial login page, because I can't log the user in before they validate via sms or email. Is there any way I can use this pre built timeout feature without logging the user in? Or having to build a custom solution myself? I'd like to avoid adding columns to my tables if possible.
